# base64: command not found - error when Cocoapods is installing BoringSSL-GRPC

Tags: ios, bash, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, cocoapods

I am building a Unity app for iOS. I am using iOS Project Builder, which allows building iOS apps on Windows. It uses Cocoapods to install Frameworks.

I have this error when Cocoapods is installing BoringSSL-GRPC:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash: line 68: base64: command not found
gunzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/gZm2RUy1

- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- Unity Version: 2020.3.12f1
- iOS Builder: 3.35.4
- iOS SDK: 14.5
- Firebase: 9.0.0

Any help would be highly appreciated.

### UPDATE 1

Not sure if bash is working. I have enabled it, but when I write it in cmd, it is displayed:

```
C:\Users\IRAKLI>bash
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

### UPDATE 2

Installed Ubuntu from Windows Store. Bash is working now from CMD, but I still have the same error with cocoapods.

Might it be the problem?

```
irakliunix@DESKTOP-U1MFKFF:/mnt/c/Users/IRAKLI$ /usr/local/bin/bash
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `base64: command not found`, then the required command `base64` need to be installed as a requirement for this script to work.

Comment: I have downloaded it and added it to Environment Variables but it didn't help.

Comment: Might be that I need to install base64 in Ubuntu. Testing it now.

Comment: https://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/help/thread.php?path=Problem%20solving/&file=bash-command-not-found&page=1#4l0v55vy7v08

Comment: The developer of the iOS Project Builder added Base64 to the program, which fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for giving feed backs and glad your issue is finally resolved.